# ViewModel set data in Activity and use in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

I am trying no implement ViewModel, plaese help me get my head around this. I wish to set data in the Activity and use it in Fragment

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),ListFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)


        var viewModel = ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory().create(TapupuViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.setData(movieList)
    }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
class TapupuViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val message  = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Movie>>()

    fun setData(msg:ArrayList<Movie>){
        message.setValue(msg)
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false)

        val model = ViewModelProvider(activity!!).get(TapupuViewModel::class.java)
        model.message.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            it?.let {
                moviesArrayList = it

            }
        })
        }
```

I am probably doing something wrong there. Can you please help me?

Comment: Hmmm, It's a little unclear what you want to achieve? send data from activity to fragment? or sharing a ViewModel between them?

Comment: I have Activity with 2 fragments who stack one on top of other. I am loading data from DB in the Activity and then I wish to use it in both fragments. Probably there is something wrong in my code, this the first time I try to implement ViewModel and with Kotlin.

Comment: Are you getting any Runtime Error?  Could you please add your error log.

Comment: @AmitGupta moviesArrayList is empty in fragment

Comment: @Dim If you're going to use MVVM you need to implement a Repository Pattern to get data from your database. What you want to implement is not logical to implement but definitely doable.

Comment: @abstractArrow I have class to get data from DB using ROOM library and Corutine.

Comment: @Dim, In your setData(msg:ArrayList<Movie>) method , you have not added way to fetch the data i.e either fetching from database or network.

Comment: @Dim are you using Room as your database?

Comment: @abstractArrow Yes

Comment: @AmitGupta Just for this example, I am setting the data from Activity

Comment: Looks like in activity, you are using some other VIewModelFactory than you use in your Fragment. That might be the reason there are actually not single but two different instances of your viewmodel class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View <---> ViewModel <---> Repository <---> Room Dao

The view is: Fragment/Activity

**No** need to share any ViewModels or ... between your Activity and Fragments.

```
class MyRepository {
    private val dao: YourDao = ...

    fun getModelFromLocal(): LiveData/RxJava/List<Model> = dao.getModel()
}
```

In your ViewModel

```
private val repository: MyRepository  = ...
val resultLiveData = MutableLiveData<SomeModelToShowOnUI>()

fun onUISentEventToLoadData() {
    val data: SomeModelToShowOnUI = repository.getModelFromLocal()
    resultLiveData.value = data
}
```

Activity/Fragment observe changes from ViewModel:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onViewCreated() {
        resultLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
            //update UI
        })
    }
}
```

Each Fragment/Activity has its own implementation.